# Why does decltype(captured_var) not behave as expected?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++17, decltype, type-deduction

```
#include <type_traits>

int x = 0;
void f(int const x)
{
    static_assert(std::is_const_v<decltype(x)>); // ok
}

int main() 
{
    int n = 0;
    [n, m = n]
    {
        static_assert(std::is_const_v<decltype(m)>); // ok
        static_assert(std::is_const_v<decltype(n)>); // err
    };
}
```

See [online demo](https://godbolt.org/z/GneG431Ka)

**Why does** `decltype(captured_var)` **not behave as expected?**

Comment: Because all captured variables are const by default if the lambda is not declared as mutable. Say `m` here, is const as expected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that in `decltype(n)`, `n` refers to the local variable `n` defined in `main()`, but not to the member of the closure type (as you expected).

[[expr.prim.lambda.capture]/11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.prim.lambda.capture#11)

(emphasis mine)

> Every id-expression within the compound-statement of a
> lambda-expression that is an odr-use of an entity captured by copy is
> transformed into an access to the corresponding unnamed data member of
> the closure type.
>
> [Note 7: **An id-expression that is not an odr-use refers to the
> original entity, never to a member of the closure type**. However, such
> an id-expression can still cause the implicit capture of the entity. —
> end note]

---

BTW: Gcc seems declaring the data member as `const` directly for non-mutable lambdas. That's why it gives `const int` for `decltype(m)`. According to the standard, [[expr.prim.lambda.capture]/10.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.prim.lambda.capture#10.2)

(emphasis mine)

> The type of such a data member is the referenced type if the entity is a reference to an object, an lvalue reference to the referenced function type if the entity is a reference to a function, or **the type of the corresponding captured entity otherwise**.

I think gcc is wrong; `decltype(m)` should lead to type `int`. Anyway, `decltype(n)` does refer to the local variable `n`, you can confirm that by e.g. changing `n`'s type to `int&&`.

[Gcc LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/tlch6gfrGn7ayZmw)
[Clang LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Z6zx4gwL2ULpxavD)

Comment: [`clang++`](https://godbolt.org/z/TGcfq8EG4)` says both `n` and `m` are non-`const`. Bug?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Because `m` is declared as `int` then `decltype(m)` leads to `int`? Even in a const-qualified member function. https://godbolt.org/z/G3T8e8qTG

Comment: @songyuanyao If that's the case, wouldn't that imply that `decltype(<any lambda capture>)` should _not be_ `const`, since that would have parity with member variables under a `const` context? Is this a specification problem in the standard? This actually appears more like a `gcc` bug to me now, since `decltype(m)` being `const` deviates from equivalent class behavior

Comment: Interesting, we're seeing different behavior with different standards and/or versions of clang.  I'm seeing that `m` and `n` are both non-const (like Ted saw), but they're both also non-mutable in the context of the non-mutable lambda.  Curiouser and curiouser.

Comment: @Human-Compiler Gcc seems declaring the data member as `const` directly for non-mutable lambdas. I checked the standard, it says the type of data member should be the type of the corresponding captured entity, so I think gcc is wrong too.

Comment: [MSVC](https://godbolt.org/z/dera64Gf9) appears to give the same output as [clang](https://godbolt.org/z/G3T8e8qTG) (no `const` for either members in a `const` context  or lambda capture). [gcc](https://godbolt.org/z/s3nocGTWW) appears to be the only one that treats the lambda capture as `const` (at least in terms of the 3 major compiler vendors). I still can't quite tell if this is an ambiguity in the standard for whether it _can_ be `const`, or whether it's just a bug in gcc.

Comment: @Human-Compiler The standard says that the `operator()` should be const-qualified for non-mutable lambdas, but declaring the data member as `const` directly seems overdoing...